# Как включить доступ к локальным дискам по сети на Win7 через c$?

Tags: windows, windows-7, администрирование

В наличии есть несколько машин с Win7 состоящие в одном домене.
На машины осуществляется логин через доменные учетные записи.
Хочется достучаться до локальных дисков по адресу компа в виде \comp1\C$
При использовании доменных учетных записей с правами локального администратора доступ работает. А при использовании локальной записи Администратора любого из компьютеров подключиться не удается. 
Для подключения к \comp1\C$
Пробую вводить comp1\Admin и его пароль.  Получаю сообщение о том, что возможно у меня нет прав для доступа к ресурсу.

Возможно кто-то знает, где и что подкрутить, чтобы доступ через локального администратора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в настройках домена. Для записи Администратор по умолчанию не был  разрешен такой доступ вообще. Создание другой локальной записи может решить проблему.